# Tesseract not recognizing text

Tags: c#, .net, tesseract, emgucv

I have emgu v3.1.0
I put tessdata (tessdata-3.04.00) folder into "Debug" folder and run my application. Buy this is not recognize nothing in my images. No exceptions. What is the trouble?

I am using LicensePlateDetector from this:
http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/License_Plate_Recognition_in_CSharp

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.Util;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;
using Emgu.CV.OCR;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Emgu.CV.Util;
using System.Text;
using Emgu.CV.Face;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace PartyRecognizer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Capture cap;
        private LicensePlateDetector textDetector;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // passing 0 gets zeroth webcam
            cap = new Capture(0);

            textDetector = new LicensePlateDetector("");
        }

        private void bnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var nextFrame = cap.QueryFrame().ToImage<Bgr, byte>())
            {
                if (nextFrame != null)
                {
                    List<IInputOutputArray> licensePlateImagesList = new List<IInputOutputArray>();
                    List<IInputOutputArray> filteredLicensePlateImagesList = new List<IInputOutputArray>();
                    List<RotatedRect> licenseBoxList = new List<RotatedRect>();
                    List<string> words = new List<string>();
                    try
                    {
                        words = textDetector.DetectLicensePlate(nextFrame, licensePlateImagesList, filteredLicensePlateImagesList, licenseBoxList);
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        Debug.Print(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
                    }

                    foreach(var word in words)
                    {
                        Debug.Print("----");
                        Debug.Print(word);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you get any exception?

Comment: There is a suspicion that egmu and tessdata versions not match, or i put lists with not valid types into DetectLicensePlate method